# I have been trying to track Events occurring in my website using JavaScript. But that code is not working

Tags: javascript

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("function reached");
  jQuery("form").submit(function() {
    analytics.track("Apply Now", {
      firstName: document.getElementById("header_form_first_name").value,
      `Help to track firstname by using ID`
    });
  });
});
```

Above code is my code in WordPress but it returns null value and I have no idea about why it is returning null value

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected template string`. You are passing an invalid object to `analytics.track`. An object is `{ key:value, key:value }` but you are passing it `{ key:value, value }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  // Use FORM ID to identify the form and invoke the submit
  $('#myForm').submit(function()
  {
   analytics.track("Apply Now", {
   firstName: 
   document.getElementById("header_form_first_name").value,
  `Help to track firstname by using ID`
  });
 }
```

Comment: I have added Form id and that is not Working. my code is actually working other html page but my code is not working in the Word press website. should i change some feature or anything?

Comment: Can you please confirm your javascript is properly interpreting  inside WordPress

Comment: To my Knowledge everything seems to be fine. I don't find any wrong interpretation in WordPress.

Comment: But If I'm correct it's a straight forward implementation, Is there any way that you can provide more details?

Comment: Yes, I can .In Word Press some has been Reporting Get element by id is not working and it is Returning Null Values.so, they advised me to made some changes and i have done that too.